# How can I use WHERE filter in Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, where-clause

Looking for some help to use the `WHERE` option in Azure CLI.

For example - I have 4 Subscriptions (Subscription1, Subscription2, Subscription3 and Subscription4), but I want to get the resources only from Subscription2 and Subscription3. How can I use a `WHERE` option while fetching the Subscriptions to look only for Subscription2 and Subscription3?

In PowerShell, it would be something like -

`Get-AzSubscription | where { $_.Name -eq "Subscription2" -or Get-AzSubscription | where { $_.Name -eq "Subscription3" }`

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like:

```
az account list --query "[?name == 'Subscription2' || name == 'Subscription3']"
```

This will only return "Subscription2" and "Subscription3" from your subscriptions list.